# How to use shared preference to send data from activity to fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to send integer value from activity to a fragment to change text size value, Iv tried user bundle and custom constructor and didn't work. 
So how can I use shared preferences for this purpose?

Comment: The most common and simplest way to do this would be to use a bundle. If you don't want to do that, you can also use an interface to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on shared preference use this code :

**To save the data**

```
 private void saveSp(String key , String value){
 PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)
            .edit()
            .putString(key, value).apply();
}
```

**To get your data:**

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context).getString("string", "default")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey have you tried something like this

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.put('key',0);
FragmentName name=new FragmentName();
name.setArguements(bundle);
Integer q=getArguments.getInt(key)
```

Comment: Hey, should I user data type Integer and not int?

Comment: Sorry should be int q=getArguements.getInt('key'); in your fragment class