# How to pass data from an Activity to a CustomView?

Tags: android

Activity B has a custom view as below:

```
public class MakePaymentCustomView extends LinearLayout {
    private Context _context;
    public MakePaymentCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        _context = context;
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.make_payment_custom_layout, this, true);
        String title;
        String subtitle;
        String[] listOfVouchers = ((MerchantDetailsActivity) getContext()).listOfVouchers;
        Log.d("LIZ OF VOUCHERS", listOfVouchers.toString());
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PaymentCustomView, 0, 0);
        try {
            title = a.getString(R.styleable.PaymentCustomView_customViewTitle);
            subtitle = a.getString(R.styleable.PaymentCustomView_customViewSubtitle);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
        // Throw an exception if required attributes are not set
        if (title == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No title provided");
        }
        if (subtitle == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No subtitle provided");
        }

        init(title, subtitle);
    }
    // Setup views
    private void init(String title, String subtitle) {
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("Automobile");
        categories.add("Business Services");
        categories.add("Computers");
        categories.add("Education");
        categories.add("Personal");
        categories.add("Travel");
        TextView titleView = findViewById(R.id.customview_textview_title);
        TextView subtitleView = findViewById(R.id.customview_textview_subtitle);
        Spinner voucherList = findViewById(R.id.voucherSpinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        voucherList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        titleView.setText(title);
        subtitleView.setText(subtitle);
    }
}
```

Activity A has a public variable named `listOfVouchers`. I am trying to access this variable from the Custom View as below:

```
Log.d("LIZ OF VOUCHERS", listOfVouchers.toString());
```

But it returns the following error:

```
com.app.ActivityA cannot be cast to com.app.ActivityB
```

How can I access the variable from Activity A in Activity B's custom view? Would need it to populate the spinner in the custom view.

Comment: You should provide a feedback on this question

Answer (score 0):

Your custom view is found in activity B , in order to save data locally and pass it on have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751209/how-to-use-shared-preference-to-send-data-from-activity-to-fragment/53797226#53797226) that covers it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is not correct. If you need the list of vouchers in the custom view, you should provide a public method on the custom view called "setVouchers", something like:

```java
public void setVouchers(String[] listOfVouchers){
  mVouchers = listOfVouchers;
}
```

where mVouchers is an instance variable of your MakePaymentCustomView class. Once you've defined the method, call it in the activity/fragment your need, in your case Activity A

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preference.
Do save your value in shared preferences.
Get your value in custom view.
After using value delete value from share preferences to avoid unknown errors.

This is not the best answer but just suggestion.